# Remove additional spaces C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have the homework assignment where I should remove all leading spaces in the char array. If there is a space in the beginning of the array, it should be deleted too. Also, I have to take care about an empty array. I can't use `<cstring>` and `<string.h>`. Also, I can't create any additional arrays. I googled a lot, but I have no idea how to solve this problem. Here is what I have so far.

```
void clean(char* tab) 
{
    //char *p = tab;
    for (int i = 0; i <= sizeof(tab); i++) 
    {
        if ((tab[i] = ' ') && (tab[i + 1] = ' '))
        {
            tab[i] = tab[i + 1];
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char tab1[] = "   h qa  w e ";
    cout << tab1 << endl;
    clean(tab1);
    cout << tab1 << endl;
}
```

Will be very gratefull if someone can give me a hint how to figure it out.

Comment: `sizeof(tab)` is wrong. This is the size of your pointer type. Usually 4 or 8.

Comment: You also are not taking into account what happens to the next character after `tab[i] = tab[i+1];`

Comment: 1.) `sizeof(tab)` is wrong - pass the size as parameter, 2.) You don't want to `i` become the size of your array, you don't even want it to become one less than the size of your array (as you use `i+1`) - Think about what range your indexes could be. 3.) What's your question?

Comment: "Leading space" and "space at the beginning" is one and the same thing, so it's not clear what are the exact kinds of space you need to remove. Perhaps show some input strings and their respective expected outputs.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Please give the ouptut expected `   h qa  w e ` or `   h qa  w e ` or `h qa  w e` or `hqawe`?

Comment: You are moving space characters into places where other space characters sit. This accomplishes precisely nothing. I recommend you take some cards with letters and blank cards, arrange them in a row, and figure out which cards you need to move, in what order and to which place. Keep track of the moves, then come up with a generic recipe.

Comment: Not giving away the solution: You want to remove leading spaces, so you don't need to iterate over the whole string. Just compare the current position to space and stop when you read another value. `num=0; while(str[num] is space) num++;` Afterwards you can just replace your old string with the string starting at `num`: `copy_from_to(str + num, str)`

Answer (score 0):

Regard each space as a "free space" in the array, one which you should fill.

You can maintain two pointers to different places in your char array. One to the first available space, another to the currently character you examine.

You only need to figure out these questions:

1. How would you fill up the spaces?
2. How would you know when you're done?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few separate problems here.

One is that you've mis-typed your comparisons: `if ((tab[i] = ' ') && (tab[i+1] = ' '))` should undoubtedly be: `if ((tab[i] == ' ') && (tab[i+1] == ' '))`.

Second, you're using `sizeof(a pointer)`, where you really wanted `strlen(a pointer)` (or at least something that works similarly, scanning for a NUL character that signals the end of the string).

Third, the algorithm your loop implements doesn't seem to reflect the intent of removing leading spaces very well (if at all). I'd scan for the first thing that wasn't a space, *then* copy the remainder of the string so it starts at the beginning of the string.

[Sorry, but I'm not going to post actual code or much more detail than that for a homework assignment.]

Answer (score 0):

Those codes work with absolutely no dependency on  nor  and they don't allocate any temporary buffers. Note that a home made `copy` function must be defined to copy string content when a space is being removed.

Note that this code is easy to understand but may/should be optimized to minimize copies if performance is a requirement.

As it's unclear what you exactly want...

This one removes **all** spaces in the string.

```
#include <iostream>

void copy( char* to, char* from )
{
    int i = 0;
    while ( true ) // risky in case char* has no EOS character!
    {
        to[i] = from[i];
        if ( from[i] != '\0' )
            ++i;
        else
            break;
    }
}

void clean( char* tab ) 
{
    int i = 0;
    while ( tab[i] != '\0' )
    {
        if ( tab[i] == ' ')
        {
            copy( tab + i, tab + i + 1 );
            // do not increment i, to test tab[i] that was newly copied from tab[i+1]
        }
        else
        {
            ++i;
        }
    }

}

int main() {

    char tab1[] = "   h qa  w e ";
    std::cout << tab1 << std::endl;

    clean(tab1);

    std::cout << tab1 << std::endl;
}
```

https://ideone.com/Yv4aqL

If you only want to remove **leading spaces**, it's even easier, just change the `clean` function:

```
void clean( char* tab ) 
{
    int i = 0;
    while ( tab[i] == ' ' )
    {
        copy( tab + i, tab + i + 1 );
    }
}
```

https://ideone.com/RIAsGt

Comment: Why don't you use `std::strcpy`? Also you could count spaces reduce a whole block of spaces at once instead of copying the whole substring everytime...

Comment: Because you are not allowed to include <cstring> in the OP....so you need to write your own copy function!

Comment: Ok, I missed that. But still it would be nicer to not copy every time a space is found.

Comment: True, I edited the post to say it could be optimized. But it works better than what the OP proposed anyway ;-)